# Convince TypeScript that an object won't be missing required keys

Tags: typescript

I have the following situation:

```
const user: UserObj = User.get(userId);

if ([user.foo, user.bar, user.baz].some((k) => !k))
  throw new Error(`Missing fields for user ${userId}`);

const createParams: CreateParams = {
  firstName: user.firstName,
  lastName: user.lastName,
  email: user.email,
  phone: user.phone,
  foo: user.foo,
  bar: user.bar,
  baz: user.baz
};
```

Because `foo bar baz` are required in `CreateParams`, TS is complaining because those keys are optional keys in `UserObj`, however, I believe I've safeguarded against that with my `.some` check, yet TS still complains. How can I convince TS that those required keys will be there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this. One way is to extract the guard into a function:

```
interface HasOptional extends UserObj {
    foo: string,
    bar: string,
    baz: string,
}

function hasOptional(user: UserObj): user is HasOptional {
    return [user.foo, user.bar, user.baz].every(k => k);
}

if (!hasOptional(user))
    throw new Error('missing fields');
```

Another way is to rewrite the conditional so TypeScript can understand it:

```
if (!user.foo || !user.bar || !user.baz)
    throw new Error('missing fields');
```

As a minor note, it can be surprising to use “truthiness” to check whether properties exist, because `!""` is true, `!0` is true, and some others. If you use `.some(k => !k)` to check for missing properties, it will throw an exception for both missing properties *and* empty strings, which may or may not be what you want. Consider whether one of the following tests may be suitable:

```
// Works if 0/''/false are legal values for foo/bar/baz.
function hasOptional(user: UserObj): user is HasOptional {
    return [user.foo, user.bar, user.baz].every(k != null);
}

// Also works if null is a legal value for foo/bar/baz.
function hasOptional(user: UserObj): user is HasOptional {
    return [user.foo, user.bar, user.baz].every(k !== undefined);
}

// Works even if undefined is a legal value for foo/bar/baz.
function hasOptional(user: UserObj): user is HasOptional {
    return ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].every(k in user);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If typescript does not trust your check, there's no other way I think. Resort to `@ts-ignore` or `||`.

```js
//@ts-ignore
foo: user.foo
// or
bar: user.bar || ''
```

If you don't like that, you can define another type to tell ts that typechecking has been done.

For example:

```js
// interface TypeChecked extends User
type TypeChecked {
   foo: string;
   bar: boolean;
   baz: any;
}

const createParams: CreateParams = {
  firstName: user.firstName,
  lastName: user.lastName,
  email: user.email,
  phone: user.phone,
  foo: (<TypeChecked> user).foo,
  bar: (<TypeChecked> user).bar,
  baz: (<TypeChecked> user).baz
};
```